# WPF application is not running after deployment and installation

Tags: c#, wpf

I deployed a WPF application with Advanced Installer. The deployment was successful and installed in PC. When I run on PC, it will not open even I run as administrator. What should I do to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the Windows Event Log?

Comment: Experienced developers will rely on application log entries in Windows Event Viewer, Process Monitor, or a debugger on that PC to reveal the missing dependencies.